# What is the query to delete a particular object from Firebase using Laravel 5?

Tags: firebase, laravel-5, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to Firebase. Still, I couldn't find a way to delete a particular object from Firebase.

```
$evnt = EventCal::where('id', '=', $id)->delete();
```

I have tried out above query to delete. But still it doesn't produce a result in Firebase. I am using `Mpociot\Firebase\SyncsWithFirebase` to sync data with Firebase.

Comment: I have never heard about laravel, but try setting the object to nil/NULL instead. Thats how it works on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

`$evnt = EventCal::where('id', '=', $id)->first()->delete();`

Without the `first()`, your query will return `[]` which is equivalent to nothing, So, delete() will not be fired.